# Controller function not running in preproduction URL ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am currently working on a web application developed using ASP.NET and C#. Within this application, I have implemented a function responsible for initiating payment transactions with credit cards. As part of this process, I define a response URL as follows:

```
string urlRespuesta = string.Format(@"{0}?cn={1}&id={2}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlRespuestaPagoVisa"], irisNIF, idPrelibro);
```

Upon successful payment processing, the expected behavior is to navigate to a view named ConfirmacionCompra.cshtml. However, an intermediate step involves invoking a function within the ClientesController.cs, specifically the ConfirmacionCompra action.

My challenge arises when I attempt to configure the urlRespuestaPagoVisa. If I set it to http://localhost:7440/Clientes/ConfirmacionCompra, the application functions correctly as it passes through the controller's action. Nevertheless, when I modify the urlRespuestaPagoVisa to a value pointing to an IIS-hosted URL, such as https://xxx.xxx.es/Clientes/ConfirmacionCompra, the view is displayed but does not pass through the controller's function.

I would appreciate guidance on resolving this behavior discrepancy and ensuring that the URL redirection functions consistently across different environments. Thank you for your assistance.

I want to work as in localhost, showing the view after passing from the controller.

HERE THE CONTROLLER CODE MINIMIZED
I'm only adding the function it should run.

```
namespace Prototipo_Arquitectura_LIE.Controllers
{
    public class MyActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        private readonly string _content;

        public MyActionResult(string content)
        {
            _content = content;
        }
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(_content);

        }
    } 
        
        
        
        
        
        /*THIS IS THE FUNCTION IT SHOULD ENTER*/
        
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ConfirmacionCompra()
        {
            int resultado,
                idPrelibro;
            StringBuilder jsonLista = new StringBuilder();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string merchanParameters,
                parametrosRecibidos,
                cifNif,
                deserializacionRespuesta,
                deserializacionCodigo,
                signatureCalculada,
                signatureRecibida,
                mensajeValidacionTipoNIF = string.Empty;
            dynamic tempDs_Response = new { Ds_Response = "" };
            dynamic tempDs_Authorisation = new { Ds_AuthorisationCode = "" };
            WSSalesForce.BookPurchaseServicePortTypeClient wsSF;
            WSSalesForce.ParamUsuario miUsuarioSalesForce;
            WSSalesForce.ParamEmpresa miEmpresaSalesForce;
            bool esSignatureOK = false;
            WSSalesForce.ParamFactura crearFacturaResponse = null;
            try
            {

                using (StreamWriter registroErrores = new StreamWriter(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"Log\RegistroErroresComprasLiweb.txt", true))
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString["Ds_SignatureVersion"] != null &&
                        Request.QueryString["Ds_MerchantParameters"] != null &&
                        Request.QueryString["cn"] != null &&
                        Request.QueryString["id"] != null &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Ds_SignatureVersion"]) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Ds_MerchantParameters"]) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["cn"]) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) &&
                        Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out idPrelibro))
                    {
                        /*****************LOGIC OF THE FUNCTIONALITY*******************/
   
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        ViewBag.PanelClass = "panel-info";
                        ViewBag.msgConfirmacionCompra = Resources.Resource.msgDatosNoRecibidosPasarela;
                        ViewBag.classConfirCompra = "fa-info-circle";
                        ViewBag.styleConfirCompra = "color:blue;";
                        ViewBag.msgConfirmacionEmail = string.Empty;
                        ViewBag.classConfirEmail = string.Empty;
                        ViewBag.styleConfirEmail = string.Empty;
                        ViewBag.IdLiweb = string.Empty;
                        ViewBag.classIdLiweb = string.Empty;
                        ViewBag.styleIdLiweb = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                wsLiWeb.GuardarRegistroError(Enumerados.EnumTypeRegError.ServicioWeb,
                                                    "ClientesController",
                                                    MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                                                    "Excepción generada" + ex.Message,
                                                    string.Empty,
                                                    DateTime.UtcNow);
            }
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the controller code?

Comment: I have edited the question to add part of the controller code